# Javascript max() for array column

Tags: javascript, math, max

Usually when I need to find the max value of an array I use this very simple code:
`var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array);`

However, now I have a multidimensional array in which for each line I have an array with 5 columns. Is there a similar way to find the max value for a certain column?
Right now I'm doing:

```
var maxFunc = function(data){
    var max = 0;
    data.forEach(function(value){
        max = Math.max(max, value[0]);
    });
    return max;
};
```

I was curious if there was a prettier/simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would write it as such:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(v => v[0]));
```

The `array.map` will transform the original array based on your picking logic, returning the first item in this case. The transformed array is then fed into `Math.max()`

To avoid creating a new array, you can also reduce the array to a single value:

```js
array.reduce((max, current) => Math.max(max, current[0]), -Infinity)
```

As you can see, we need to add the initial value of `-Infinity`, which is returned if the array is empty.

Answer (score 9):

This is a great application for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
max = data.reduce(function(previousVal, currentItem, i, arr) {
    return Math.max(previousVal, currentItem[0]);
}, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

This also avoids the bug in your code that would happen if all the values in `data` are less than `0`. You should be comparing against `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` rather than `0`.

Alternatively, you could normalize the data before reducing to the max value:

```
max = data.map(function (d) {
    return d[0];
}).reduce(function (p, c, i, arr) {
    return Math.max(p, c);
});
```