# Is there any function in jQuery that is equivalent to PHP's array_column()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What is the equivalent to PHP's `array_column()` in jQuery? I need the data inside the **array** without looping, in the same way as in PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190407/javascript-max-for-array-column

Comment: anything you use will loop the array, regardless if it's a native method or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848004/get-column-from-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: impossible in jQuery (even more impossible without a loop, be it visible or invisible to the naked eye)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do it with [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Immagine a fetch of database rows.

**With arrow function**

To have a reusable `arrayColumn(array, column)` function:

```js
const array = [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
];
const arrayColumn = (array, column) => {
    return array.map(item => item[column]);
};
const names = arrayColumn(array, 'name');
console.log(names);
```

Or you can use `.map` directly:

```js
const array = [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
];
const names = array.map(item => item.name);
console.log(names);
```

**Before ES6 (2015)**

```js
var array = [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
];
function arrayColumn(array, columnName) {
    return array.map(function(value,index) {
        return value[columnName];
    })
}
var names = arrayColumn(array, 'name');
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 10):

Shorter version of Fabian's answer using arrow notation:

```
let array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    },
];

let names = array.map( el => el.name );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [];
data.push({col1: 1, col2: 2});
data.push({col1: 3, col2: 4});
data.push({col1: 5, col2: 6});

Array.prototype.getColumn = function(name) {
    return this.map(function(el) {
       // gets corresponding 'column'
       if (el.hasOwnProperty(name)) return el[name];
       // removes undefined values
    }).filter(function(el) { return typeof el != 'undefined'; }); 
};

console.log(data.getColumn('col1'));
```

Result

```
Array[3]
0: 1
1: 3
2: 5
```

It is possible to skip the `.filter` part just by taking the first element of array and checking if it has the corresponding key. But some rows might not have that key at all, while others might have it.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of this post is my JavaScript implementation of PHP's [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php). No jQuery needed.

Example usage:

```
var records = [
    {id: 2135, first_name: 'John',  last_name: 'Doe'},
    {id: 3245, first_name: 'Sally', last_name: 'Smith'},
    {id: 5342, first_name: 'Jane',  last_name: 'Jones'},
    {id: 5623, first_name: 'Peter', last_name: 'Doe'}
];
var first_names = arrayColumn(records, 'first_name');
// => ["John", "Sally", "Jane", "Peter"]
var last_names = arrayColumn(records, 'last_name', 'id');
// => {2135: "Doe", 3245: "Smith", 5342: "Jones", 5623: "Doe"}
var persons = arrayColumn(records, null, 'id');
// => {
//        2135: {id: 2135, first_name: 'John',  last_name: 'Doe'},
//        3245: {id: 3245, first_name: 'Sally', last_name: 'Smith'},
//        5342: {id: 5342, first_name: 'Jane',  last_name: 'Jones'},
//        5623: {id: 5623, first_name: 'Peter', last_name: 'Doe'}
//    }
```

Implementation:

```
/**
 * Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33841999/1402846
 *
 * This function is (almost) equivalent to array_column() in PHP (http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php).
 *
 * Differences between this function and PHP's array_column():
 * <ul>
 *     <li>If <code>indexKey</code> is not found in an element of the input array, the behaviour of this function is undefined.
 *     In PHP's array_column(), the element will be put into the end of the array. It is possible in PHP because PHP does not
 *     distinguish between arrays and dictionaries, but it is not possible in JavaScript because Arrays and Objects are different.
 *
 *     <li>Associative arrays (dictionaries) in PHP are ordered, JavaScript objects are not (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/14028460.
 *     Do not make assumptions on the ordering of the keys in JavaScript objects.
 *
 *     <li>If the value of an element at <code>inputKey</code> is not a string, the result of this function and the PHP function
 *     doesn't make much sense. For example, in PHP,
 *     <code>
 *          $records = array(
 *              array('id' => true, 'last_name' => 'Doe')
 *          );
 *          array_column($records, 'last_name', 'id');
 *     </code>
 *     gives <code>Array([1] => Doe)</code>, or maybe <code>Array([0] => Doe)</code> due to a bug ({@link https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68553}). But, in JavaScript,
 *     <code>
 *          var records = [
 *              {id: true, last_name: 'Doe'},
 *          ];
 *          arrayColumn(records, 'last_name', 'id');
 *     </code>
 *     gives <code>{true: "Doe"}</code>. Therefore, it is strongly advised to make sure that the value at <code>indexKey</code> of
 *     each input element is a string.
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param {Array|Object} inputArray             The input array, it must either contain objects only or arrays only.
 *                                              If it is an object instead of an array, it would be converted to an array first.
 * @param {int|string|null} columnKey           If the input array contains objects, this parameter is the key in each object.
 *                                              If the input array contains arrays, this parameter is the index in each array.
 *                                              If the key or index is not valid, this element is skipped.
 *                                              This parameter may also be <code>null</code>.
 * @param {int|string|null} [indexKey=null]     If the input array contains objects, this parameter must be a valid key in each object.
 *                                              If the input array contains arrays, this parameter must be a valid index in each array.
 *                                              If it is not a valid key or index, the behaviour is undefined.
 *                                              This parameter may also be <code>null</code>.
 * @returns {Array|Object}                      If <code>indexKey</code> is <code>null</code>, this function returns an array which is parallel
 *                                              to the input array. For each element <code>elem</code> in the input array, the element in the
 *                                              output array would be <code>elem[columnKey]</code>, or just <code>elem</code> if <code>columnKey</code>
 *                                              is <code>null</code>.
 *                                              If <code>indexKey</code> is <b>not</b> <code>null</code>, this function returns an object.
 *                                              For each element <code>elem</code> in the input array, the output object would contain an
 *                                              element <code>elem[columnKey]</code>, or just <code>elem</code> if <code>columnKey</code>
 *                                              is <code>null</code>, at the key <code>elem[indexKey]</code>. If the value of <code>elem[indexKey]</code>
 *                                              of some elements in the input array are duplicated, the element in the return object would
 *                                              correspond to the element nearest to the end of the input array.
 * @example
 * var records = [
 *      {id: 2135, first_name: 'John',  last_name: 'Doe'},
 *      {id: 3245, first_name: 'Sally', last_name: 'Smith'},
 *      {id: 5342, first_name: 'Jane',  last_name: 'Jones'},
 *      {id: 5623, first_name: 'Peter', last_name: 'Doe'}
 * ];
 * var first_names = arrayColumn(records, 'first_name');
 * >> ["John", "Sally", "Jane", "Peter"]
 * var last_names = arrayColumn(records, 'last_name', 'id');
 * >> {2135: "Doe", 3245: "Smith", 5342: "Jones", 5623: "Doe"}
 * var persons = arrayColumn(records, null, 'id');
 * >> {
 *      2135: {id: 2135, first_name: 'John',  last_name: 'Doe'},
 *      3245: {id: 3245, first_name: 'Sally', last_name: 'Smith'},
 *      5342: {id: 5342, first_name: 'Jane',  last_name: 'Jones'},
 *      5623: {id: 5623, first_name: 'Peter', last_name: 'Doe'}
 *    }
 */
function arrayColumn(inputArray, columnKey, indexKey)
{
    function isArray(inputValue)
    {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(inputValue) === '[object Array]';
    }

    // If input array is an object instead of an array,
    // convert it to an array.
    if(!isArray(inputArray))
    {
        var newArray = [];
        for(var key in inputArray)
        {
            if(!inputArray.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
                continue;
            }
            newArray.push(inputArray[key]);
        }
        inputArray = newArray;
    }

    // Process the input array.
    var isReturnArray = (typeof indexKey === 'undefined' || indexKey === null);
    var outputArray = [];
    var outputObject = {};
    for(var inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputArray.length; inputIndex++)
    {
        var inputElement = inputArray[inputIndex];

        var outputElement;
        if(columnKey === null)
        {
            outputElement = inputElement;
        }
        else
        {
            if(isArray(inputElement))
            {
                if(columnKey < 0 || columnKey >= inputElement.length)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(!inputElement.hasOwnProperty(columnKey))
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            outputElement = inputElement[columnKey];
        }

        if(isReturnArray)
        {
            outputArray.push(outputElement);
        }
        else
        {
            outputObject[inputElement[indexKey]] = outputElement;
        }
    }

    return (isReturnArray ? outputArray : outputObject);
}
```

Comment: why it is sorting default, e.g. If I change the order in the given array then it should result in the same order as given. But it is always sort by key.

Comment: @DeepKakkar What do you mean sort by key? Can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to build an object ~ php like associative array. by selecting the .id of the source array, and build that id as the index of the new array and contains the same content of the old source array.

```
var categoriesById={};

for(item in cacheObject.Categories){
categoriesById[cacheObject.Categories[item].id]=cacheObject.Categories[item];
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You mean like this:

```
var a = {};
a['alfa'] = 0;
a['beta'] = 1;

alert(a['alfa']);
```

Comment: does not answer the question

Comment: Read the question properly.